# WPF is binding a child control's width to a parent control's actualwidth a bad idea?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, actualwidth

I guess I am curious because I found an infinite loop in which the child was being sized larger and then the parent got larger repeatedly and fixed it.  However, I'm wondering if perhaps it is a better idea to just override measure and find the parent's size and then return the desiredsize instead. By not changing `Width` or `Height`, I eliminate the possibility of creating an endless loop. On the flip side, by not binding the width in xaml, how the width of the control is being determined is now hidden in code-behind.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: this has the issue that I need to have a nonzero size to the element in the first place, but it should work.

Comment: you could set MinWidth, I suppose

Comment: yeah, this is a good idea that I also found elsewhere after looking up how stretch works. Unfortunately in my situation, I am drawing off of the ActualWidth of the control, and horizontalalignment affects layout without changing that property, so I can't just use it.